# Is there any argument against declaring a variable in C++ with auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I find the `auto` keyword to be very useful as I don't have to worry about the type outcome of evaluating a complex expression or having to worry about which type to use (in terms of the right size) when initializing a variable. Besides backwards compatibility, is there any reason why I shouldn't use auto or circumstances in which it's not wise to do so ?

Comment: I would never use `auto`.  It doesn't do _anything_.  What do you mean by "don't have to worry about the type outcome of evaluating a complex expression or having to worry about which type to use"?

Comment: @SteveSummit auto variable = some_long_expression (type is unknown, could evaluate to double, int, etc.)

Comment: One argument against is that the actual type becomes hidden when reading the code. If you do multi-step transformations with auto, it can be quite hard to follow the type changes.

Comment: Ah. It's an old, old keyword that's taken on a new life.  I'm an old C programmer who hadn't heard of this new usage.